# How to check if the datetime field of a record is minor than current datetime?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of `match` that isn't played yet, now I need to know if the `datetime` field which contains the exact day and hour of start is minor than the current `datetime`. How can I achieve a similar thing?

*Data sample*

```
| id | round_id | datetime      
   1     1365     2018-08-19 07:00:00
   2     1365     2018-08-08 11:00:00
   3     1365     2018-07-28 07:00:00
   4     1365     2018-07-27 11:00:00
   5     1365     2018-07-29 07:00:00
```

so as you can see we have 2 `match` that play the next month (August), and three `match` that play in the current month `July`. 
So the query should return `true` because there almost a match that have a `date` minor that the current date, which means that this `match` has already played. If instead the `matches` with the id: 3, 4, 5 weren't in the list, then the query should return `false`.

*What I tried*

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN m2.datetime < NOW() THEN true END), false)
       FROM `match` m2 WHERE m2.round_id = 1365
```

the `query` return always `true`, and this is really strange, could someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Without a group by aggregation (ie min) will be over the whole resultset and since your min datetime is before now() the query returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't even need a true/false, you can simply just reference it. `m2.datetime < NOW()` is in fact a boolean, and adding `IF` or a `CASE` statement is simply redundant:

```
SELECT m2.datetime < NOW() AS `is_less_than_today`
FROM `match` m2 WHERE m2.round_id = 1365
```

See the sample fiddle <kbd>[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae510/3)</kbd>.

EDIT (Will return 1 true or false value):

```
SELECT SUM(m2.datetime < NOW()) > 0
FROM `match` m2
WHERE m2.round_id = 1365
GROUP BY m2.round_id
```

See the updated fiddle <kbd>[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cae510/9)</kbd>.

Comment: but if I want return simply a single result that means that almost a match have a date minor than the current?

Comment: @Jidic Can you clarify what you mean by "minor"? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: for example: 2018-07-27 is minor than 2018-07-28. I don't need as result a list of matches, just to know if there is one match that have as datetime field a value that is minor to the current date

Comment: Oh yeah, that's why it sounded strange to me, I could not find the term, I'm sorry :P

Comment: @Jidic Alright, I updated my answer. We know that `m2.datetime < NOW()` gets you want you want, you just want to see if one row matches that, so we can simply `SUM()` up all the true/false values, and checking if they're `> 0` will determine if any are true.

Comment: but if instead I want invert the result? I mean instead of return true I want return false, should I change with `m2.datetime > now()`?

Comment: Try it, and see if it works. I linked the dbfiddle there, you can try some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `MIN` function,just use `CASE WHEN` can make it.

```
SELECT *,(CASE WHEN m2.datetime < NOW() THEN true else false END)
FROM `match` m2 
WHERE m2.round_id = 1365
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake area

According to description there is no need to use `min` function but you used that as a result it returns only minimum date which is `2018-07-27` therefore you got always `true`

The things that you have to do just remove `min` and you forget to put `else` in your  query so put that  it will work perfectly as your expectation

as you want single date use `min` inside `case when`

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN min(m2.datetime )< NOW() THEN true else false END
   FROM `match` m2 WHERE m2.round_id = 1365
```

Comment: I don't need as result a list of matches, just to know if there is one match that have as datetime field a value that is minor to the current date

Comment: then in your query min function need

Comment: @Jidic as you want single date use `min` inside `case when`